# hosting Reactjs site on varcel fails to find import path that is seemingly correct

Tags: reactjs, hosting, vite

i am trying to host my reactjs site on varcel. 
the site has several assets, site runs completely fine on my local.

the problem occurs when i am trying to host it, it fails to import the asset.
throws

> error during build:
> Error: Could not resolve '../../assets/portraits/1.jpeg' from src/Pages/Contact/Contact.jsx

the import statement goes like

```
import P1 from "../../assets/portraits/1.jpeg";
```

the dir structure is like

```
src
 > assets
  > icons
  > portraits
    >1.png
    >2.png
```

i am frustrated beyond measures, any help would be really appreciated
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to save all your images in public folder and then using absolute path to import that images. For example structure like this

```html
public
  > portraits
    > 1.jpeg
    > 2.jpeg
```

then
`import P1 from "/portraits/1.jpeg";`